# How to improve my proof and whether or not one condition in the statement is important in writing the proof?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

A simple graph $G$ is connected iff for every partition of the vertices into two non-empty sets $X$ and $Y$, there is a vertex $x\in X$ and a vertex $y\in Y$ such that $xy$ is an edge of $G$.

My proof:

$(\Rightarrow: )$ Since $G$ is connected, then every pair of vertices $v,w$ there is a path in $G$ from $v$ to $w$. We partition the vertices into two non-empty sets $X$ and $Y$, pick two arbitrary vertices $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, then there is a path from $x$ to $y$. The path contains at least $1$ edge. We pick the edge where the endpoints are one in $X$ and other in $Y$ (but I am really not sure how to explicitly show this). Let the endpoints be $x'\in X$ and $y'\in Y$ and hence $x'y'$ is an edge in $G$.

$(\Leftarrow: )$ We arbitrarily partition the vertices of $G$ into two non-empty sets $X$ and $Y$, let the vertices $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ be such that $xy$ is an edge in $G$. Since the partition is arbitrary, there always exists a path from any $x'\in X$ to $y'\in Y$ (I am also not so sure how to write this part rigorously). Hence we can conclude that $G$ is connected.

Is my proof correct? And how can I fill in some missing parts in the proof?

The thing that I doubt is that *I did not use the fact that $G$ is a simple graph*. How should I include that in my proof? I am not sure whether the fact that $G$ is simple is important in the statement.

Could somebody please give some help and clarification on it? And some advice on how to improve the proof please? Thanks!

Comment: ($\Rightarrow$:) "We pick the edge where the endpoints are one in $X$ and other in $Y$": does this edge exist? (I know it does, but you haven't proven it.)

Comment: @shardulc Yes you're right. I am not really sure how to show that. I have made some edit to the post. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: ($\Leftarrow$:) "Since the partition is arbitrary, there always exists a path from any $x' \in X$ to $y' \in Y$": In the sentence before this, you said that a path exists between some two vertices in any two partitions. But now you are claiming that a path exists between any two vertices. How does this follow? (Hint: can you make special partitions?)

Comment: For the first part, a hint is to think about all the vertices you will cover in your path. Will all of them be in $X$? in $Y$?

Comment: @shardulc For the partition, yes I am not sure how to explain that in more detail. Also, can we make special partition? We need to show every partition, isn't it better if we use arbitrary partition?

Comment: For the second part, you don't need to show that it holds for every partition. It is given to you that for every partition, there exists... you just have to use this fact however you want to to show that $G$ is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ($\Rightarrow$:) part is almost complete, except where you are not sure. We pick $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, and we know that there is a path between them. Let the vertices in this path be $x, a_1, a_2, \dotsc, a_n, y$. The first vertex is in $X$, and the last vertex is in $Y$; all vertices are either in $X$ or $Y$ and never in both. Consequently, there will be two adjacent vertices in the path where one is in $X$ and the other is in $Y$ (if this never happened, how do you get from $X$ to $Y$?). Let these vertices be $x'$ and $y'$, respectively. Since they are adjacent in the path, there is an edge between them and the proof is complete.

For the ($\Leftarrow$:) part, a different approach is required (in my opinion). If $G$ has no vertices or only one vertex, then the proof is trivial. If there is more than one, let $X$ contain only one vertex $x$ and let $Y$ contain the rest. By our assumption, for some $y \in Y$, the edge $xy$ exists.

Now include $y$ in $X$ and remove it from $Y$. Note that $X$ is a connected graph because a path exists between any two of its vertices. Repeat the above procedure: for some $x_1 \in X$ and some $y_1 \in Y$, the edge $x_1y_1$ exists. Now include $y_1$ in $X$ and remove it from $Y$. Again, note that $X$ is connected because for any two vertices in $X \setminus y_1$, a path exists between them; and a path exists between one vertex in that set and $y_1$, so they are all connected. Repeat this procedure until all the vertices are contained in $X$. Now $G$ itself is connected, and the proof is complete.

(I, too, cannot see why $G$ must be simple, so perhaps this is a more general property than what you have been asked to prove.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there is one thing that concerns me, how do we know $X$ is connected as what you said? The statement doesn't seem to say that explicitly.

Comment: @user338393 Edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: Yes it is clear now. Thanks!